# How to monitor data pattern of a particular field in the microservice response over a period time

Tags: java, spring-boot, stream, microservices

I need to monitor the pattern of Json response over a period of time from a microservice to ensure the data quality. Depends on the pattern, will have to make some decision in the application flow. This requirement is similar to analyzing the click pattern in a stream, however the need here is to perform similar analysis from a microservice response within a given timeframe. Can anyone please suggest a framework or idea to do it. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to measure? If you're looking to only sample a data source when the source is stable, perhaps you can look into measuring a rolling variance. When the variance is low, the data source is stable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Once in a while the external backend API service is returning default cached response like  "Not Found" , "No Data" with 200 status code instead of the expected API response. I would like to catch these kind of dummy responses. Currently, its difficult to capture these responses as its not  falling error/exception category.

Comment: What do you mean by capture? Log the response? Record a metric? Retry the service call? An appropriate solution might be to make a thin proxy class around your backend client which implements the same interface as the backend client. This proxy can be used to delegate calls to the real client and inspect the response before returning the value to your application logic.

Comment: I need to retry the service call after some point in time when the backend service becomes healthy and sending successfull response (not dummy response(.

Comment: This is called a transient exception and there are many valid ways of dealing with this problem. Depending on the amount of work you'll have to throw away you can perform retries in the backend client or bubble up the exception for a downstream process to perform the retry. What you'll want to keep in mind is how long these outages in the backend last and leave a certain amount to time to wait before retrying. I usually opt for multiple retries with "exponential backoff" for repeated failures. ie after each failure increase the time between retries as to not overwhelm your backend service.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. But the scenario here is that response is Success, not an exception.

Comment: Have your application logic throw an exception, or you can use the proxy pattern to wrap the call, examine the response, and throw an exception in this scenario.